# How do the different isolation_levels behave in sqlite3 python library?

Tags: python, sqlite

Looking at the documentation here:
 http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions

I can't seem to figure out how the different isolation_levels behave (other than None sets it to auto-commit).

Seems like I'm not the only one that has this problem: http://bugs.python.org/issue8145

Does anyone have any idea how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [the SQLite documentation for BEGIN](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).